# Активация 2 и 3 чекбоксов при нажатии первого

Tags: gtk

Есть такой код:

```
    void ShowCheckBox(GtkWidget *window, GtkWidget *vbox)
{
    GtkWidget *check1, *check2, *check3, *progress;

    check1=gtk_check_button_new_with_label(_U("Главная опция"));
    check2=gtk_check_button_new_with_label(_U("Второстепенная опция"));
/*  Найти решение как сделать активной третью кнопку после нажатия первой */

    check3=gtk_check_button_new_with_label(_U("Вторая второстепенная опция"));

    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check3, FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check2, FALSE);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(check1), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(CheckToggled), (gpointer) check2);


    progress=gtk_progress_bar_new();
    gtk_progress_bar_set_pulse_step(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(progress), 0.05);
    g_timeout_add(100, (GSourceFunc) ShowBarPulse, (gpointer) progress);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), check1, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), check2, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), check3, FALSE, TRUE, 0);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), progress);
}
```

Второй чекбокс активируется следующим кодом:

```
    void CheckToggled (GtkToggleButton *check1, GtkWidget *check2)
{
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(check1))
    {
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check2, TRUE);


    }
    else
    {
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check2, FALSE);

    }

}
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии первого активировался еще и третий?
Как сделать, чтобы третий активировался при нажатии второго?
PS. Ай эм сильно начинающий, поэтому как сказал известный персонаж, прошу отнестись с пониманием))
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил следующую строчку:

```
gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check3, FALSE);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(check1), "toggled", G_CALLBACK(CheckToggled2), (gpointer) check3);
```

И для активации третьего чека сделал

```
void CheckToggled2 (GtkToggleButton *check1, GtkWidget *check3)
{
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(check1))
    {
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check3, TRUE);


    }
    else
    {
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(check3, FALSE);

    }

}
```

Но может есть другое решение?